# Renaming and moving file using NSFIleManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is my code to rename and move file from a temporary directory to My Documents directory.

So the problem is within two sections of mode Create a Directory and Attempt to move. The rest all is working correctly..

When I comment out the Create directory section, the Attempt to Move section logs in the console:

> Unable to Move the File..Error Code 4.

Now I researched error code 4 and it means that the directory does not exist. So I added the code to create the directory.

Now when I run the program the directory is created but the Attempt to Move section logs:

> Unable to Move File..error code 512

Now researching on it it is due to the file already exists. The destination must not exist.

So I am pretty confused, since both error codes are contracting each other.

```
{
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager* manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; 
    NSString* tempFile =[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recordTest.caf"];
    if (tempFile) 
    {
        // Get the Documents Directory
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
              [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

        //Get the User File Save Name from the text field
        NSString *UserText =   [[self FileNameText] text];

        // Rename the file, by moving the file
        NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory 
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:UserText]];

        // Create a Directory
        if( [manager createDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,UserText]  withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]!= YES) 
       {
           NSLog(@"Directory error");
       }

        if([manager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,UserText]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Path exist");
            NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
                  [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
        }
        // Attempt the move
        if ([manager moveItemAtPath:tempFile toPath:filePath2 error:&error] != YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to move file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            if ([manager removeItemAtPath:tempFile error:&error] != YES)
                NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    [manager release];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the file you are trying to move doesn't exist.

replace

```
if (tempFile) //this will return YES every time, telling you you have a string!
```

with

```
 if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:tempFile]) //this will tell you if the file exists at that path
```

---

**A few notes**

**1.** To see with your eyes if the file you are looking for really exists, check the simulator application folders at something similar to this:

> /Users/yogevshelly/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications

then browse to a specific application

**2.** Don't just append strings to get folders , do something like this:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**3.** The following line will create a folder with the file's name as the folders name!:

```
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:filePath2  withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]
```

creating a folder from a filename seems weird, what you want to do is either copy the file to an existing directory or first create a directory and copy the file into-it

Comment: hey man..thanks for your answer..can you also tell me..should i remove the item at temporary directory too..since everything is working now..except that it is logging unable to delete file(error 4) in my portion to removeItemAtPath ?

Comment: Since you used 'moveItemAtPath' you already deleted the file, so the 'removeItemAtPath' line is redundant

Answer (score 0):

you use the metod

```
contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: withIntermediateDirectories: attributes:error
```

this method create directory but you pass it the filename.
i think you create /Documents/filename/ instead of /Documents/filename

Comment: i am just `using that contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` to log in the console..my actual code does not contain that

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the problem part of the code is following one

// Create a Directory

```
if( [manager createDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,UserText]  withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]!= YES) 
   {
       NSLog(@"Directory error");
   }
```

You are creating a folder in with the file name in same location .... try commenting the the above code .. it should work.